# Economics of grid extension versus off-grid electrification in developing countries

Tags: development-economics, energy-economics

Quite a bit of research is available on the local economic effects of electrification in communities in developing countries ([this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030142159290108E) and its references go into quite a bit of detail on the topic).

However, with the advent of microgrid technology, and the increasing cost-effectiveness of distributed energy resources (particularly solar), it seems that the calculus would change.

I am wondering what effect (if any) small-scale, local energy resources would have on a local economy, in contrast to simple extension of a centralized grid.

Most of the research I am able to find around "microgrid economics" or "distributed energy economics" is either in the context of communities moving from centralized to de-centralized energy (e.g., hospitals installing a microgrid to improve energy reliability), or is simply a cost comparison of the expense of electrification using the two different methods.